# How do I export all email addresses associated with an Email Alert?

Tags: soql, email-alert

I need to generate a **list** (csv, Excel, etc) of **all Recipients of a particular Email Alert**.

This alert contains Roles, Users and specific email addresses as Recipients, but I need a **list of each and every *Email address*** that the Alert ultimately gets sent to.

I've searched, and can not find a way to do this that works.   Is this possible via SOQL?   Does anyone know exactly what tables are involved in storing this data (or where I'd even look that up)?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can query workflowalert object using tooling api.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowalert.htm